# How to use Backend Object in FrontEnd TypeScript (MEAN Stack)

Tags: node.js, angular, http, typescript, mean-stack

Using MongoDB, express.js, angular4, node.js

A string I retrieve is well retrieved, but not the same as a full object...

**account.service.ts** (full, )

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
const jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private authService: AuthService) {}

  user: any[];

  currentUser() {
    if(this.authService.isAuthenticated()){
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
      return decoded.user;
    }
  };

 getProfile() {
const id = this.currentUser();
return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/user/" + id).
  map(
  (response: Response) => {
    const data = response.json();
    return data;
  }
)
  .catch(
    (error: Response) => {
      console.log(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json());
    }
  )
}
```

**user-profile.component.ts**

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  user: any;

  constructor(private account: AccountService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.account.currentUser();
    this.user = this.account.getProfile()
      .subscribe(user => {
              this.user = user;
              return this.user;
            });
  }

  logUser() {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.user);
  }
}
```

**user-profile.component.html**

```
  <p>{{user}}</p>
  <p>User with ID {{id}} Loaded</p>
  <a (click)="logUser()">Log User Test</a>
```

HTML file shows:

```
[object Object]

User with ID 59ca916323aae527b8ec7fa2 Loaded
```

What I get from clicking "log User" link is the retrieved ID string and the user object:

> 59ca916323aae527b8ec7fa2
>   [{...}] //clicking this reveals all of the object's details.

But I can't make that step of getting those details and presenting them in the HTML as I successfully managed with the ID... I mean, {{user.anything}} doesn't fetch the user's data as it should

May I have some assistance?

Comment: could you please show your full AccountService class?

Comment: Yeah, I have added the full class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getProfile()` to,

```
getProfile() {
    const id = this.currentUser();
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/user/" + id).
      map(
      (response) => response.json()
    )
      .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
          console.log(error);
          return Observable.throw(error.json());
        }
      )
    }
```

Also, in `ngOnInit()` change this one,

```
this.user = this.account.getProfile()
      .subscribe((user) => {
              this.user = user;
            });
```

See if it gives you the right output.

**EDIT**

Change this one,

```
this.user = this.account.getProfile()
          .subscribe((user) => {
                  this.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
                });
```

**EDIT-2**

```
this.user = this.account.getProfile()
              .subscribe((user) => {
                      this.user = JSON.stringify(user);
                      this.userObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
                      // also try, this.userObj = user; if above line didn't work
                    });
```

Define another property in component as ,

```
userObj: any;
```

Refer to the object in template as this

```
{{ userObj[0]?.email }}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
It works just like before - in the user-profile component "LogUser" successfully prints out the ID, and the user object is also retrieved inside the [{..}] Object (hovering above it says "Object")

Comment: Try this on the template: `<p>{{ user | json }}</p>`. (using json pipe)

Comment: This changed the html output from [object Object] to [ { "_id": "59ca916323aae527b8ec7fa2", "gender": "male", "birthday": "2017-09-07", "email": "test@test.com", "password": "hashed.password", "__v": 0, "name": { "firstName": "name", "middleName": "test", "lastName": "name" } } ]
And also supplied an error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: apart from the error, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It seems like the right direction... to ngOnInit I added: 
this.user = JSON.stringify(user), then on HTML: {{user}} gives the same result as the piped result, except there is no error now, but {{user.email}} for instance is still not being displayed...

Comment: That is because the `user` currently is just a string. Convert it back to an object using `JSON.parse()` and see if that produces the right output. See the 'EDIT' in my answer

Comment: It brought it back to being an object;
{{user}} = [object Object] and {{user.email}} doesn't display anything again
I'm currently browsing to understand the method in which I can retrieve the data I need from that JSON string

Comment: Your response seems to be a list. Are you expecting one profile or more than one?

Comment: Just one profile...
    `console.log(typeof this.user);` prints out `'string'`

Comment: It seems to be working for everyone else lol...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729907/angular2-http-display-json-specific-values

Comment: Try my updated answer. In your case, you are getting the resulting response as a list though: `[ { "_id": "59ca916323aae527b8ec7fa2", "gender": "male", "birthday": "2017-09-07", "email": "test@test.com", "password": "hashed.password", "__v": 0, "name": { "firstName": "name", "middleName": "test", "lastName": "name" } } ]`

Comment: It successfully presenting the property I need!
BUT with a weird error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined` which I'm trying to get rid of

Comment: Okay, use the `?` elvis - operator for that. `{{ userObj[0]?.email }}`

Comment: OK I FIXED IT!
The problem was rooted in the list, which was rooted in the controller which used the `User.find` method instead of the `User.findById` method. Now it doesn't bring back a list anymore and I successfully manage to display {{user.email / whatever data}} and without any TypeErrors
Thank you so so so so so much amal!!!!!!!!

Comment: Good that you fixed the root problem! Glad to help :)